# imperfect subjunctive - might

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

At the end of the **Michel Thomas Spanish Advanced Course**, he talks about the imperfect subjunctive. While it seems there are good examples using **si** clauses, he says it can also be used to invoke **might**.  I cannot find a reference to this translation anywhere else, so does this have merit?

*lo hubiera comprado* - I might have bought it
*quisiera* - I might want
*hiciera* - I might do
*lo hubiera hecho* - I might have done it

etc...

While the course is far from perfect, it is usually genius in its grammar explanations. However, this is news to me.

Besides *quisiera*, can these expressions be used like this alone without *si* or *que* clauses etc, and would they mean **might**?

Comment: In fact, the actual tense that carries the sense of "might" is the conditional: _lo habría comprado_, _querría_, _haría_, _lo habría hecho_, but that tense and the imperfect subjunctive have been used indistinctly in Spanish for centuries in these cases.

Comment: Does the course provide any examples? I am used to seeing conditional perfect ("habría comprado") replaced by pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo ("hubiera comprado") meaning "would have bought". This is correct as explained [here](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/subjuntivo-en-condicionales-569/). But I cannot think of examples with the meaning "might have bought" that do not include additional words like "podría" or "quizá".

Comment: @wimi The examples are the ones I gave above from the course.

Comment: @Charlie *lo habría comprado* means "I would have bought it" not "I might have bought it"...

Comment: @Jonathan I mean example sentences. Does the course not provide example sentences?

Comment: @wimi Those are the example sentences from the course. It is a sentence builder.  Example: "Lo hubiera vendido." - I might have sold it.

Comment: @Jonathan if those are the only examples the course provides, it does not seem like a very good course. A "sentence" like "I might have sold it" does not tell me anything about the context in which such an expression can be used, so I do not learn anything from that example. On the other hand, an example like "If I had not spent so much money on other things, I might have bought a car" tells me what the meaning of "I might have bought" is. Without such context, it does not seem like anyone is coming up with an example of when the imperfect subjunctive is equivalent to "might"...

Comment: @wimi Regardless of rating the course, I am just trying to figure out if "might have" can be a possible translation when outside of a "si" clause etc.  As I already said, I am looking for explanations outside of the course.

Comment: @Jonathan I would translate "If I had not spent so much money on other things, I might have bought a car" as "Si no hubiera gastado tanto dinero en otras cosas, **quizá habría/hubiera** comprado un coche", where both "habría" and "hubiera" are valid, but the word **quizá** is needed in order to convey the meaning of "might". The word **quizá** can be substituted by others, such as "posiblemente", or "puede que", but "hubiera" alone is not enough to convey the "possibility" meaning that the word "might" has. Does this go in the direction of answering your question?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, it turns out that Michel Thomas is correct, but only in some cases.

1.) The past subjunctive can only be used in a clause **by itself**  in 3 cases, none which translate as **might**:

https://spanish.yabla.com/lesson-Very-Polite-Independent-Clauses-Using-Subjunctive-683

- **quisiera** lit *I wanted* - **(I / you / he) would like...**
- **pudiera** lit *I could / I was able to* - **Could (I / you / he)...**
- **debiera** lit *I would have to / should* - **(I / you / he) should...**

https://www.lawlessspanish.com/grammar/verbs/imperfect-subjunctive/

---

2.) One use of the subjunctive mood in English and in Spanish is to show doubt or uncertainty.  The word **may** shows doubt in the subjunctive present, and the past tense of *may* is **might**, hence it is the *past subjunctive / imperfect subjunctive* tense.

[https://www.enago.com/academy/may-or-might/#:~:text=The%20grammatical%20distinction%20between%20the,and%20might%20the%20past%20tense](https://www.enago.com/academy/may-or-might/#:%7E:text=The%20grammatical%20distinction%20between%20the,and%20might%20the%20past%20tense).

- **no pienso que venga** - *I don't think that he MAY come*
- **no pensé que que viniera** - *I didn't think that he MIGHT come*
- **no pensé que hubiera venido** - *I didn't think that he MIGHT HAVE come*
- **no pensé que hubiera estado venido** - *I didn't think that he MIGHT HAVE BEEN coming*

However, we would most likely say:

- **that he is coming / that he is going to come / that he will come**
- **that he was coming / that he was going to come / that he would come**
- **that he had come**
- **that he had been coming**

https://espanol.lingolia.com/en/grammar/subjuntivo/preterito-pluscuamperfecto

---

So, in reality, he really just needed to clarify that it cannot be translated as **might** by itself, and not in all cases.